# Not able to read all the child project user stories from Parent project in Rally Rest Toolkit for Java

Tags: java, rally, code-rally

I was trying to read all the user stories(including child project user stories) from a parent project using the java toolkit. But its not reading all the user stories

below is my code snippet
`QueryRequest  existUserStoryRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
        existUserStoryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String [] {"FormattedID","Name","Attachments"}));
        existUserStoryRequest.setProject(projectOID);
        existUserStoryRequest.setScopedDown(true);
        existUserStoryRequest.setLimit(3000);
        existUserStoryRequest.setScopedUp(true);
        QueryResponse userStoryQueryResponse = restApi.query(existUserStoryRequest);`

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors?  Part of the problem may be related to the way you are setting scoping- it needs to be a ref rather than an oid...

```
existUserStoryRequest.setProject("/project/" + projectOID);
```

Comment: HI Kyle, I am not getting any error, but its not reading all the child project data from Parent scope.